# Adding extra item to RecyclerView (Mixing data from local storage with Online Server Data)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm inflating RecyclerView with data received from server call. Now I want to add one more item to this RecyclerView from local storage(i.e. one drawable and one string manually). Let me show few of my code and tried methods which have not worked for me yet.

FragmentCategoryList.java:

```
CategoryAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<CatDataItem> dataItems;
ArrayList<ExtraDataItem> extraItems;

void getCategories() {
            ApiGetCategories.getInstance().setListener(this);
    }

@Override
    public void onGetCategories(CategoriesModel categoriesModel) {
        isLoading = false;
        dataItems = categoriesModel.getData();
        setAdapter();

    }

void setAdapter() {
        if (adapter == null) {
//tried method            dataItems.addAll(dataItems.size()+1, extraItems);
            adapter = new CategoryAdapter(dataItems, getActivity());
            recyclerCategory.setAdapter(adapter);
            setLayoutManager();
        } else {
//tried method            dataItems.addAll(dataItems.size() +1, extraItems);
            adapter.updateList(dataItems);
            setLayoutManager();
        }
    }
....
```

CategoryAdapter.java extends RecyclerView.Adapter:

```
private ArrayList<CatDataItem> dataItems;

public CategoryAdapter(ArrayList<CatDataItem> dataItems, Context context) {
        this.dataItems = dataItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void updateList(ArrayList<CatDataItem> dataItems) {
        this.dataItems = dataItems;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

@Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_raw_category, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.tvCategory.setText(dataItems.get(position).getName());

        Glide.with(AppController.getInstance())
                .setDefaultRequestOptions(new RequestOptions()
                        .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .load(ApiClient.IMAGE_URL + dataItems.get(position).getImg() + ".png")
                .into(holder.ivCategory);
        holder.mainContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (onCategoryClick != null) {
                    onCategoryClick.onClickCategory(position);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataItems.size();
    }
....
```

CatDataItem.java:

This is getter setter class and used com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

```
...
 @Override
    public String toString() {
        return
                "DataItem{" +
                        "id = '" + id + '\'' +
                        ",name = '" + name + '\'' +
                        ",img = '" + img + '\'' +
                        ",description = '" + description + '\'' +
                        "}";
    }
...
```

CategoriesModel:

```
@SerializedName("data")
    private ArrayList<CatDataItem> data;

    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;

    public void setData(ArrayList<CatDataItem> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public ArrayList<CatDataItem> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return
                "CategoriesModel{" +
                        "data = '" + data + '\'' +
                        ",message = '" + message + '\'' +
                        "}";
    }
```

ExtraDataItem extends CatDataItem:

I had set static values to id, name, img and description parameter. Everything is same as CatDataItem.

Everything works fine and inflates very beautiful view having 3x* grid.
But now I wants to add one more item at the beginning of the first item. So want to move all items to one index further. Also the extra item is from local storage while all other data is coming from remote server API call.

So I'm not able to trace out perfect way to add one string and image to first position in RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after trying many methods, I have got perfect answer for this question.

First Declare DataItems element:

```
CatDataItem ee;
```

Then inside onCreateView add some values to this element.

```
ee = new CatDataItem();
ee.setId("0");
ee.setName("Add");
ee.setImg("animals_pets");
ee.setDescription("desc");
```

And finally add that element to position 0 in DataItems:

```
@Override
    public void onGetCategories(CategoriesModel categoriesModel) {
        isLoading = false;
        dataItems = categoriesModel.getData();
        dataItems.add(0, ee);
        setAdapter();

    }
```

Thank You.

Hope this might help lots of people who wants to mix local and online data.